# Thevenin Nodal analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, nodal-analysis

[image]

Anyone has any idea how to deal with this tricky circuit using Thevenin?

Comment: First off, why don't you use the schematic editor that is available so that we have IDs for each part? Second, why not explain to us some of your own thoughts about an approach as well as why you realize (or imagine) that they aren't going to work? Just talk a little bit about things. All you've done here is through a picture at us and ask us to tell you how ***we*** think. You'd save us a lot of time if you'd first show us how you think about things, first.

Comment: *Anyone has any idea how to deal with this tricky circuit using Thevenin?* Sure, I'd apply Thevenin where I can and see how that would simplify things. What would your suggestion be to apply Thevenin?

Comment: This is not Chegg. We will not do your homework for you. You must show a significant amount of your own effort and then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded an image to get you started. After one source transformation, define all unknown currents in the circuit. You can create five unique equations using four unknown currents and Vo, with two KVL's and three KCL's. I have written four of these equations for you. Complete the left KCL, and you will have a system of equations which includes Vo. Solving this system leads to the solution to Vo that you have shown in your question. I hope this helps you.[image]